# Get query string parameter from href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to obtain the value of the variable view_data_id and store inside another variable called view_data_id_fk.

The last line of code doesn't seem to work on my end, so I'm wondering how I can go about doing it?

```
var view_data_id = val['view_data_id'];

// How to obtain the value of view_data_id?
<td><a href="datamapmain.php?view_data_id='+view_data_id+'" 
class="link">Link</a></td>

//Will be passed on to ajax file
view_data_id_fk:$('.link').val();
```

Comment: jQuery method `.val()` only applies to form tags like input, select, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value using jQuery and `attr(..)` method (or just standard JavaScript) and regular expressions :

jQuery:

```
var q = $('.link').attr('href').match(new RegExp('[?&]view_data_id=([^&#]*)'));
var view_data_id_fk = q ? q[1] : '';
```

Standard JavaScript:

```
var q = document.querySelector('.link').href.match(new RegExp('[?&]view_data_id=([^&#]*)'));
var view_data_id_fk = q ? q[1] : '';
```

[Edited, thanks to [Alexei Levenkov]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477420/alexei-levenkov)

There is a standard way to do this, with `URLSearchParams` api, but it has limited browser support ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Browser_compatibility)):

```
var q = new URLSearchParams(document.querySelector('.link').href).get('view_data_id');
var view_data_id_fk = q || '';
```

Comment: RegEx is bad way to parse urls - please use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a reusable function as below

```
function getUrlParam(url,name){
  var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
  var results = regex.exec(url);
  return results === null ? '' : 
                     decodeURIComponent(results[1]).replace(/\+/g,'');
}
```

Get the href attribute value using JQuery `var url = $('.link').attr('href')`

```
var view_data_id_fk = getUrlParam(url, 'view_data_id');
```